# WebDAV "Add Network Location" Not Valid in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, apache2, webdav

I have created a WebDAV share over https (self-signed) on an Ubuntu server using Apache2.

When I try to add it as a network location (on Windows 10) it fails saying the folder is not valid.

I tried to map it to a drive using `net use p: https://example.com/webdav` but it fails saying `System error 1790 has occurred. The network logon failed.`

My Apache config is:

`Alias /webdav /var/www/webdav
 <Directory /var/www/webdav>
        DAV On
        AuthType Digest
        AuthName "webdav"
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/users.password
        Require valid-user
        RewriteEngine off
        Satisfy all
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        ForceType application/octet-stream
        Options Indexes
    </Directory>`

Cyberduck can connect to the drive using https.

When I switch back to http, it all works. Is there a problem with Windows accepting self-signed certificates?

Comment: See if this gets you started in the right direction: https://moblog.wiredwings.com/archives/20110406/webdav-windows-7-and-self-signed-certificates-howto.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It doesn't work on Winsrv 2012/2016/2019 using HTTP protocol, you have to use HTTPS with a valid certificate on the webdav configuration!

i know is too late for you 555, but it could help others!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a problem with Windows accepting self-signed certificates?

Definitely.

No sane operating system would accept an untrusted certificate.
Which is exactly what you should expect.
Otherwise, what would certificates be useful for?